# Leitura de Biometria

Tags: c#, .net

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema desktop, onde eu queria fazer o cadastro de uma biometria. Eu uso o leitor `Futronic Modelo: FS80H`. Sou novo em .net

A ideia é salvar a biometria em formato `String` para posteriormente ser salvo em um banco de dados.

Comment: Tá, e qual sua dúvida? já foi no fabricante ver como faz a interface ? http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_sdk_win.html

Comment: Já fui no site do fabricante e não existe nada especificando como fazer, não encontrei nenhuma documentação. A minha duvida é Ler a impressão digital e salvar em uma variavel do tipo String

Comment: veja se te ajuda https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/document-imaging/fingerprint-scanner-csharp/

Comment: no link q passei tem as informações, vc ainda pode baixar um exe de exemplo e a DLL que faz a comunicação. Há ainda esse outro link: http://www.futronic-tech.com/download/SDK_Windows_brochure.pdf

Comment: A sdk é fornecida pelo fabricante do aparelho até onde eu entendi. Mas como eu vim do java eu estou acostumado com bibliotecas e jars abertos de codigo livre, c# seria mais ou menos o inverso, as dll seriam pagas?

Comment: Não é que as dll seriam todas pagas. O que acontece no seu caso específico é que a fabricante optou por cobrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que consegui verificar é que, para usar o hardware de impressão digital da futronic, você precisa adquirir uma licença de sdk da própria fabricante, sem essa licença você não conseguiria por meios legais o acesso. Ao adquirir a licença você recebe toda a documentação.